# Postgresql substring to extract between angle brackets and quotes

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, substring

I have a field that has xml. I'm trying to extract data from an attribute which is followed by the `>` that resides at the end of an element's start tag.

E.g.

I require the 250 from the scale attribute.

```
<Request id=""1111"" order=""123456"" scale=""250""><Project file=""test.txt""/></Request>
```

I wish to extract it using substring. So I did:

```
select substring(myxml from '%scale="#"%#""><Pro%' for '#') from mytable
```

This returns 250 which is what I want.

But, the problem is that the next element for other records doesn't always start with `<Pro`

So I tried this

```
select substring(myxml from '%scale="#"%#""><%' for '#') from mytable
```

It returns:

```
250"><Project file="test.txt"/></Request>
```

Where am I going wrong? Is there a better way? 
Many thanks.

Comment: Are the `""foobar""` typos ? Seems too many double quotes

Comment: Not typos. That's how the data has been formatted and inserted into the field.

Comment: This is not valid XML

Comment: Correct. This is just how it's stored. It's been deliberately manipulated to have double double quotes for some reason.

Comment: Can you explain a bit this reason ? I wonder why on earth generating wrong XML is needed.

Comment: I can't give you an answer to that sorry.  I just have this data, and which to extract. It was generated before my time.

Comment: When your XML isn't valid XML, I would fix that problem first. All other problems will be much easier to fix and you (finally) have valid XML. XML is also a native datatype in PostgreSQL and has some nice functions for handing this data.

Comment: Thanks Frank. Unfortunately I'm not in the position to change the data. I can only manipulate it in my query to get the results I need. I'm going to explore regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are always certain that you are after the `scale` attribute in the `Request` element, then this may work for you (I only tried this on PG 9.3.5):

```
SELECT (regexp_matches(myxml, '<Request[^>]*?\s+scale=""(\d+)""'))[1] AS scale FROM mytable;
```

Some contrived mock data (I varied both the `scale` value and the inner element name) as a demonstration:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM mytable;
                                             myxml                                         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 <Request id=""1111"" order=""123456"" scale=""250""><Project file=""test.txt""/></Request>
 <Request id=""1111"" order=""123456"" scale=""250""><Notproject file=""test.txt""/></Request>
 <Request id=""1111"" order=""123456"" scale=""253""><Notproject file=""test.txt""/></Request>
(3 rows)

postgres=# SELECT (regexp_matches(myxml, '<Request[^>]*?\s+scale=""(\d+)""'))[1] AS scale FROM mytable;
 scale
-------
 250
 250
 253
(3 rows)
```

The regular expression I used above expects the value of `scale` to be comprised exclusively of digits.  If your data might be more varied than that, the capture portion may need to be something like `([^"]+)` instead of `(\d+)`.

Comment: Thanks rchang! I'd fooled around a bit and instead of (\d+) I used ([0-9]*)